# How do I construct a concrete real number in lean without errors? failed to synthesize instance OfScientific ℝ

Tags: lean4

How do I fix

```
limit_linear_khan_academy.lean:22:16
Messages (1)
limit_linear_khan_academy.lean:22:13
failed to synthesize instance
  OfScientific ℝ
All Messages (4)
```

code?

```
def c : ℝ := 0.5
```

Comment: You should provide a self-contained piece of code, so that anyone can directly pull up the code and see the error for themselves.

Comment: My guess is that you didn’t import the reals.  Try `import Mathlib` at the top.  Without that or similar, Lean thinks ℝ is a new type.   This “feature” is quite controversial.  (Also the Reals are not in base Lean.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import Real numbers:

```
import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic

def c : ℝ := 0.5
#eval c
```

output

````
Real.ofCauchy (sorry /- (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, (1 : Rat)/2, ... -/)
```
````